# Notification bar welcome msg causes page render glitch on scroll up in Chromium

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome, notification-bar, rendering

[image: Stack notification glitch screenshot]

When scrolling up using arrow keys or mousewheel, the bottom few pixels of the welcome message notify bar are left 'trailed' on the screen. Moving over certain elements refreshes these areas (i.e., logo and 11m ago). If I scrollwheel fast enough, the space between the glitches increases. This happens on any Stack Exchange site with such a welcome message that I haven't clicked [x] on, logged in or out. I've finally just registered so can't advise on the notification bar's other uses (or directly post a screenshot).

I'm using Chromium 17.0.946.0 (Developer Build 110888 Linux) Built on Ubuntu 11.04, from https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa but I'm sure this happened in Chromium 15 before I moved from Ubuntu to Arch.

This could be an on-going Chromium bug, but I thought I'd try report it here first. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. [Here it is on Code Review](http://i.imgur.com/Kl3pp.png), eek! That was using F5, End, hold down Up Arrow.

Answer (score 3):

It's rather obvious that this is a bug in Chromium, Webkit, Cairo (or whatever graphics library they're using), Compiz, or whatnot, and not one of ours.

And since to reproduce it you have to do mouse wheel acrobatics in a non-supported browser (i.e. it's not of the category "not our fault, but we have to do something about it as it impacts lots of people"), it's not worth to even consider finding a workaround.

Comment: That's fair enough. I have had this bug for months though - what versions of Chromium are supported by the site? I can boot into my old drive and retest there with the non-nightly (if it is supported). I can report the bug with the Chromium folk instead also.

Comment: The current and previous version is supported, whatever that means for  Chrome. This afternoon, it's apparently 15. Anyway, even in a supported version, this wouldn't really change anything. I mean, look at your description how to reproduce it -- you basically pushed buttons until finally a graphics error appeared :)